# How to get Physijs and Threejs to work together with tQuery

Tags: three.js, physics-engine, physijs, tquery

Good evening,

I recently switched from EaselJS to Threejs, it's amazing!

I've tried to include a physic engine called Physijs and use it with tQuery with this [tutorial](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/06/05/3d-physics-with-three-js-and-physijs/) but it's not working.

Head:

```
<!-- Physics engine -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/tquery-bundle-require.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ammo.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/physi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/tquery.physi.js"></script>

<!-- Game and GameCore namespace -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.static.js"></script>
```

Physijs version: latest form GitHub
Threejs version 59 (included in tQuery)
tquery.physi.js version: unknown, grabbed from the source-code of the tutorial, can't find it anywhere else)

init function called when the page's loading is complete:

```
var world = tQuery.createWorld().boilerplate({cameraControls: false}).start();
world.tCamera().position.set( 70, 40, 70 );
world.tCamera().lookAt( world.tScene().position );
world.tRenderer().shadowMapEnabled   = true;
world.tRenderer().shadowMapSoft       = true;
world.tRenderer().setClearColorHex( 0xffffff, 1 );
world.enablePhysics();
```

Error given by FireBug:

```
TypeError: world.enablePhysics is not a function
world.enablePhysics();
```

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this problem,?
Feel free to talk about alternative too! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess [tQuery project](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/tquery/) died, because last commit was made on Jul 25 2013. So you will have to work out without [Jeromeetienne tQuery tutorials](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/categories/tquery/) and his [tQuery project](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/tquery/). It seems that [Jeromeetienne has started new extension system for threejs, called threex](http://www.threejsgames.com/extensions/).